# Executing prepared statement with PhP

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, executequery

I'm still very new in PhP, and I have this statement here:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `Date` = ''',
      `Date`,
      ''' THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS `',
      `Date`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Days;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Name, ', @sql,'
                     FROM Days
                    GROUP BY Name
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

and I'm trying to execute it with Php so I have the same html table like in this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37156/8

Answer (score 0):

When I use prepare statements like this I return `fetchAll` from the function that the sql is in.  That returns an array of all the data.

I can then format it in the HTML page as I see fit by:

```
$data = nameOfYourFunctionThatReturnsFetchAll;

<?php echo '<li>' . $data['nameOfFieldFromDatabase'] . </li> ?>
```

Etc etc

EDIT:

```
<?php 

function getData(){

sql here
try{
execute sql here
}catch PDOException($e){
$e->getMessage();
}
return fetchAll();
}
```

then

```
$data = getData();
```

then in your HTML

```
<?php echo '<li>' . $data['name'] . </li> ?>
```

You need to know that values within the $data['name'] refer to the names of the field in your database so make sure they match

Comment: Ok, I put the entire statment in $data variable, and the executed: <?php echo '<li>' . $data['name'] . </li> ?> to test it, I I just got one letter like result. Is this what I should be doing?

Comment: "the entire statement into a variable" ?! Put it in a function :)
Then create the variable from the result of that funciton.

I'll update answer in a second with an example I use.